# Javascript: Compare each line of a textarea with all lines of another textarea

Tags: javascript, html, textarea

I need to compare each line of  textarea "a" with all lines of textarea "b" , and create an alert() with all items of "a" who doesn't exists in "b"

¿ How can i do this ?

Answer (score 1):

One way could be to get the values of the 2 textareas and split them on newline (`\n`) characters. You can then iterate over the lines of the first textarea and check to see if they appear in the second textarea:

```
var t1 = document.getElementById("textarea1").value.split("\n"),
    t2 = document.getElementById("textarea2").value.split("\n"),
    notIn2 = [];
for(var i = 0; i < t1.length; i++) {
    if(t2.indexOf(t1[i]) === -1) {
        notIn2.push(t1[i]);  
    } 
}
```

There may well be a better way, and I'm sure the above is far from perfect. This is just what came to mind first. Here's a [working example](http://jsfiddle.net/2EFTZ/2/).

Comment: I was JUST about to post the same! +1 for being quicker ;) However, I would use `.split(/\r\n|\r|\n/);` just to be safe.

Comment: I have no idea what's happening, var t1 is empty after do 
var t1 = document.getElementById("textarea1").value.split("\n");

Comment: It will only split on explicit new line characters (where you have pressed Enter for example). If there are new lines in the textarea with `id` "textarea1", `t1` will contain an array.

Comment: EPIC FAIL. I've forgotten to ADD my box to the CGI params, i fixed it, and it's working now.
Sorry, and thanks for all!!!!!!!!